# why does std::filesystem::path::root_name() return empty string?

Tags: c++, windows, c++17, std-filesystem

I have below sample code which I ran on visual studio 2019 and on https://godbolt.org/. I can see that there are two different behavior. What could be the possible reason ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>


int main()
{    
    std::filesystem::path p("//net");    
    std::cout << "root name of " << p << " is " << p.root_name() << std::endl;
}
```

Output in visualstudio 2019 :    root name of "//net" is "//net"

Output in https://godbolt.org/ : root name of "//net" is ""
[image]

I Just read http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4100.pdf - 8.4.9 path decomposition [path.decompose]
but did not understand the reason.

Also, I read below code in the `std::filesystem` but din not understand completely

```
        _NODISCARD path root_name() const {
        // parse the root-name from *this and return a copy if present; otherwise, return the empty path
        return _Parse_root_name(_Text);
    }
```

Is there anyone who can explain me in more detail to understand the problem ?

Comment: Maybe it is a UNIX / Windows file naming issue?

Comment: Linux technically doesn't include a root name. `root_path` returns the right path though (`/`)

Comment: If std::filesystem is in any way similar to boost::filesystem internally, [this might be relevant](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html): "Because there is no root name (i.e. drive specifier or network name), a lone slash (or backslash) is a relative path on Windows but an absolute path on POSIX-like operating systems.". `root_name()` is probably meant for Windows and other operating systems that actually have root names

Answer (score 2):

Compiler Explorer runs most of its compilers on a **POSIX** system.  POSIX *allows* an implementation to interpret a leading `//foo` similarly to how Windows interprets a leading `\\foo`: as a host name for a network filesystem.  (Windows actually supports either kind of slash, as seen in your example.)  However, modern implementations do not do this (relying instead on automounting in some directory like `/net`), so `//foo` just means `/foo`, which like everything else is under the one Unix root directory `/`.  `filesystem::path` doesn’t count that global root as having a **name** in the sense of `\\host` or `C:` from Windows.